# Login registration fails to login in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been trying to connect my database with php codeigniter framework because I'm creating a login form for my project, but I've been having problems form validation callback. even if i'm inputting the correct username password. it still gives me incorrect username/password.

Here's my code for the `database.php` located at `application/config`:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'users';
$db['default']['password'] = 'p455w0rd';
$db['default']['database'] = 'users';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Here is the code for my login controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_login extends CI_controller{

    public function index()
    {
        $this -> login();
    }

    public function login(){

        $this->load->view('login');     
    }

    public function members(){
        $this->load->view('members');
    }


    public function login_validation(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //$this->form_validation->CI =& $this;

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');

        if($this->form_validation->run($this) == false){
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
        else{
            redirect('c_login/members');
        }

    }

    public function validate_credentials(){

        $this->load->model('model_users');

        if($this->model_users->can_log_in()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials', 'Incorrect username/password');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

my model_users:

```
<?php

class Model_users extends CI_Model {

    public function can_log_in(){

        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

It would be a really great help if you guys can help me fix this problem. i'm using XAMPP 1.7.3a.

Comment: Fix 'this problem'? What is the problem, are you getting any errors? What is going wrong?

Comment: whenever i try to input the username and password, even if its correct, it still gives me incorrect username password.

Answer (score 0):

remove md5 from this statement

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');
```

you are converting here password into md5 after that you again convert password in your model

```
  $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
```

i think that's the problem

Comment: it still wont work, i tried it and still gave me an incorrect username and password, the username and password are right but still wont enter to the user page

Comment: are you inserted password as MD5 format in database

Comment: yes, but i also tried not having an md5 format, still wont work the same way

Comment: i think its got something to do with 
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;